# C++: Returning a class variable

Tags: c++, class, variables

When I try using a method to return a private variable, it seems the value changes from since the object was constructed.  Here is my code and output.

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "coordinate.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Coordinate c(1, 1);
    cout << c.getX() << endl;

}
```

coordinate.cpp

```
#include "coordinate.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

Coordinate::Coordinate(int x, int y)
{
    x = x;
    y = y;

    cout << x << endl;

}
```

coordinate.h

```
#ifndef COORDINATE_H
#define COORDINATE_H

class Coordinate
{
    private:
        int x;
        int y;

    public:
        Coordinate(int x, int y);

        int getX() { return x; }
        int getY() { return y; }
};

#endif
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Do not post screenshots of text.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your constructor is assigning to its arguments instead of the object's private fields. Use an initialization list, or explicitly qualify the assignment targets with `this`, or pick different argument names:

```
Coordinate::Coordinate(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) {
    cout << x << endl;
}
```

or

```
Coordinate::Coordinate(int x, int y) {
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
    cout << x << endl;
}
```

or

```
Coordinate::Coordinate(int xVal, int yVal) {
    x = xVal;
    y = yVal;
    cout << x << endl;
}
```

Comment: Or even better, use the constructor's initialization list, and you won't need the `this->`. `Coordinate::Coordinate(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) { ... }`

Comment: @Praetorian: Good point. I'm more used to Java, which doesn't have those.

Answer (score 2):

Within the constructor, `x` refers to the argument, rather than the member variable, so `x = x` is an assignment of the argument to itself. The member variables remain uninitialised.

You can avoid this problem by using a member-initialiser-list or by explicitly referring to the member variable through `this->x`.

```
Coordinate::Coordinate(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y)
{
    cout << this->x << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try assigning the values to private member variables using `this` pointer like this?

```
Coordinate::Coordinate(int x, int y)
{
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;

    cout << x << endl;
}
```

or what you can do is to change the parameter names in constructor to avoid using `this` pointer

```
Coordinate::Coordinate(int a, int b)
{
    x = a;
    y = b;

    cout << x << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
Coordinate::Coordinate(int x, int y)
{
     this->x = x;
     this->y = y;

     cout << this->x << endl;

}
```

First time you get value of **x = 1** because its value of argument **'x'** that got print. but second time you got it wrong because, member variable x never get any value assigned.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with these assignments:

```
x = x;
y = y;
```

You are actually assigning the constructor parameters `x` and `y` to themselves, and not from the parameters to the object's `x` and `y` members.

Also, this line

```
cout << x << endl;
```

prints the constructor parameter `x` and not the object's `x` member.

**You are hiding members `x` and `y` by using the same names as the constructor parameters' names.** Referencing the names `x` and `y` without qualifying them would refer to the parameters and not the object's members.

You can solve this problem by doing something like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=be87ed5a8962d365066819a3f4e54c55-f674c1a6d04c632b71a62362c0ccfc51). In that, I prefixed the member variables with `m_`. You can also do some other similar techniques.

Answer (score 0):

uselease replace the variable names as :

```
class Coordinate
{
    private:
        int a;
        int b;

    public:
        Coordinate(int x, int y)
       {
         a = x;
         b = y;

         cout << x << endl;
       }

        int getX() { return a; }
        int getY() { return b; }
};
```

Actually the compiler is getting confused which value of x to use,  plz use some other variables in private section. Otherwise you can use this to resolve this also as:

```
 Coordinate(int x, int y)
       {
         this->x = x;
         this->y = y;

         cout << x << endl;
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

With these code:

```
x = x;
y = y
```

you are assign x and y to themselves.

```
Coordinate::Coordinate(int xVal, int yVal)
{
    x = xVal;
    y = yVal;

    cout << x << endl;
}
```

is okay.

the best way is:

```
Coordinate::Coordinate(int xVal, int yVal):x(xVal),y(yVal)
{
    cout << x << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out

```
Coordinate::Coordinate(int x, int y)
{
    x = x;
    y = y;
```

This is a condition called "shadow variables". The values "x" and "y" in the function prototype shadow the member variables, and thus "x = x" assigns the value of parameter x to the parameter x.

Compilers like GCC and Clang will warn you about this. MSVC doesn't because Microsoft's API is a bit messy and they use a hell of a lot of the symbol table :)

A widely used way to avoid this is prefixes. "m_" for "member", "g_" for "global", "s_" for "static".

```
class Coordinate
{
    // by saying 'class' instead of 'struct',
    // you declared the initial state to be "private".
    int m_x;
    int m_y;
    ...


Coordinate::Coordinate(int x, int y)
    : m_x(x)
    , m_y(y)
{}
```

Some folks take this a step further and use a prefix - or suffix - for parameter names; I picked up adding "_" from several Open Source projects I worked on.

```
Coordinate::Coordinate(int x_, int y_)
    : m_x(x_)
    , m_y(y_)
{
    int x = m_x;  // assign from member value
    int y = y_;   // assign from parameter
    std::cout << x << ", " << y << std::endl;
}
```